# Defining bytes in a specific offset in EMU8086

Tags: assembly

How can I define bytes in a specific offset in EMU8086. I use `org` command but it does not work. How can I do that. My code is as follows:

```
org 100h
lea si,dgs
lea di,dgs2
mov al,'r'
etk:scasb
jnz etk
mov bl,[di]


ret
org 150h
dgs     db 'bekir oflaz$'
org 200h
dgs2    db 'mehmer kaplan$'
```

I thought `bekir oflaz$` string will start from 150th offset address. But in my tests it starts right after my code block. `lea` commands stores correctly the offsets of the variables (150h and 200h). But variables are stored wrong position.

Comment: I don't know if there's a better way, but you could probably insert some `db N dup(X)` statements to place your strings where you want them.

Comment: I know it. But there must be an easy and straightforward technique.

Comment: `org` is a virtual directive. it computes offsets for already mapped to system memory code. it doesn't physically pad bytes. `db <bytes_count> dup(0)` is pretty easy and straightforward, don't you think so?

Answer (score 1):

The `ORG` directive in EMU8086 doesn't seem to work if there is more than one `ORG`, unlike other assemblers, which pads bytes from the end of one section to the beginning of the next section that the next `ORG` creates.

So `DB/DUP` is the most straightforward technique I know. I don't know if EMU8086 support macros. If so, you may create a macro like this:

```
orgpad     macro pos
           db (pos-$) dup 0
orgpad     endm
```

And use it whenever you need to align code or data to a certain position:

```
orgpad 150h
dgs     db 'bekir oflaz$'
orgpad 200h
dgs2    db 'mehmer kaplan$'
```

If macros are not supported, just place the `DB/DUP` directive in your code/data:

```
        db (150h-$) dup 0
dgs     db 'bekir oflaz$'
        db (200h-$) dup 0
dgs2    db 'mehmer kaplan$'
```

Comment: "org" never worked this way in any assembler. For example the first org does not insert 100h bytes at the beginning of the file. Org only sets the internal address that is used in assembly process. For example the label "dgs" will have value of 150h and "dgs2" value of 200h. But the above macros will do the job.

Comment: The PASMO assembler, for instance, does that: the first ORG does indicate the start of code. Subsequent ORGs pad bytes from the current position to the address they define

Comment: @johnfound it works exactly like that in GNU `as`, it will specifically output padding to the given address.

Comment: gas is not assembler :P